# PRODUCT IF - Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, product

I'm looking to multiple some numbers together if the numbers are within a certain time period e.g 2002 - 2008. I can create a `PRODUCT(IF(` function that will allow me to do this for a single criteria, however when I try using `PRODUCT(IF(AND(` with 2 criteria, then the product returns 0. Please see below for examples - I've picked a trivial second criteria which will obviously hold:

```
2001    1.018
2002    1.015
2003    1.031
2004    1.025
2005    1.032
2006    1.026
2007    1.045
2008    1.042
2009    1.000
2010    1.050
```

`{=PRODUCT(IF(A1:A10>=2003,B1:B10))} = 1.279331`

`{=PRODUCT(IF(AND(A1:A10>=2003,A1:A10>=2002),B1:B10))} = 0`

These answers should logically produce the same result as the second criteria trivially holds.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try this array formula,

```
=PRODUCT(IF(A1:A10>=2003, if(A1:A10>=2002, B1:B10)))
```

Array formulas don't like AND or OR since they are a form of array processing already.

I hope your actual example is something else since the logic here is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for the data in the range `>=2002` and `<=2003`.
Try the array formula:

```
=PRODUCT(IF(((A1:A10)<=2003)*((A1:A10)>=2002),B1:B10))
```

Using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of `ENTER` to confirm.